# what is the performance of a datastore kindless query vs an access by key?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

Although our system has only unique keys, we willing to use kinds for better organize and run some operations. 
Edited-> This means that I wouldn't know beforehand in what kind the ID will be.

It would be very useful to query for an ID in all the kinds we have.

[Datastore does have this option](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-kindless-query-nodejs). What I want to do is to create a query like this:

```
const query = datastore.createQuery()
  .filter('__key__', '=', uniqueKey)
  .limit(1);
```

to replace access by key in an specific kind.

As we frequently access by key and key access is considered a [small operation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) (so it costs less) , I am trying to figure out if the code above will perform as good as key accesses.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering capability you mention is intended mostly for cases where you don't actually know the key(s) beforehand, filtering, etc.

You shouldn't need to perform such query to obtain the single entity matching that key (if any). Simply retrieve the entity by direct key lookup (which key access really is), it is the recommended way. From [Retrieving an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity):

> To retrieve an entity from Cloud Datastore, use its key for a lookup:
>
> ```
> datastore.get(taskKey)
>   .then((results) => {
>     // Task found.
>     const entity = results[0];
>
>     // entity = {
>     //   category: 'Personal',
>     //   done: false,
>     //   priority: 4,
>     //   description: 'Learn Cloud Datastore'
>     // };
>     console.log(entity);
>   });
> ```

You also don't need to query for a single ID in a kind, instead you can build the corresponding key (that's a local operation, doesn't hit the datastore) and perform they key lookup. From [Kinds and identifiers](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers):

> The following example creates a key with kind `Task` using a key name,
>   "sampleTask", as the identifier:
>
> ```
> const taskKey = datastore.key([
>   'Task',
>   'sampleTask'
> ]);
> ```

Comment: Thanks, Dan. My challenge is that the specific key can be in one of the several kinds I have and I don't know beforehand what kind it will be. Actually in my current design with only one kind, I can successfully use keys, but if I group JSONs into different kinds, I can't do it no more. So my question wether using kindless queries would perform the same way as key access.

Comment: The kindless queries filtering needs keys, not IDs, so you still need to get the keys first.

Comment: It not seem to be like this, including the name seems to refers to a not obligatory use of kind. From the google manual: A query with no kind and no ancestor retrieves all of the entities of an application from Cloud Datastore. Such kindless queries cannot include filters or sort orders on property values. They can, however, filter on entity keys and use ancestor filters. Key filters can be used by specifying __key__ as the property name:

Comment: That refers to the query itself - you don't need to specify the kind, but in the query you propose you need to specify the key, which has the kind embedded in it. I agree, my earlier comment is misleading, by `The kindless queries filtering` I didn't mean all such queries - that would be, indeed, wrong - I meant the queries like the one you proposed.